# java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key

Tags: java, gradle, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup signal-cli (https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli) on my Raspberry Pi 2.

I installed it successfully, but when I try to register a new phonenumber java is throwing out the following error:

```
Error loading state file "/home/osmc/.config/signal/data/xxxxx": javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: Could not derive key
```

Haven't found any solutions anywhere on the web.

Comment: Its already [discussed](https://github.com/AsamK/signal-cli/issues/5).

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: This is a generic exception that could be a symptom of a configuration issue or a problem with the cryptographic primitives.  Most likely a configuration issue.  Which version of Java are you using?  Do you have unlimited strength crypto installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by downgrading to JRE 7.

Not sure if the Dev is gonna add Java 8 support anytime soon.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue with old WS. In java 8 there are missing old ssl handshakes. Adding [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) and adding to Security providers it with following code

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

worked for me

Hope it helps you and others